# How to assign a PHP expression to a PHP variable

Tags: php

I need to do something like

```
  $var = "Hello World ..the value is <?php echo 'XYZ' ?>";
```

Any help will be highly useful. I am stuck in this from the very long time but not able to acheive this. please help

Below is my PHP code that I need to assigned again to php variable (this variable will be passed to return of my ajax call)

```
<div class="photo-post">
    <h4 class="h4-1">Some data...</h4>

    <?php
    $i=0;
    $unique_seq="888094499";
    $pic_counter=1;
    foreach (glob("target/*".$unique_seq."*") as $filename) 
    {
        $i++;        
    }
    $total_pics=$i;
    echo "<div id='post-photo-slider'>";
    if($i>1)
    {
        echo "<a  href='#' class='control_next_photo'>></a>";
        echo "<a  href='#' class='control_prev_photo'><</a>";
    }
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach (glob("target/*".$unique_seq."*") as $filename) 
    {
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<div class='photos-slide-container'>";
        echo "<img src='".$filename."' width='540px' height='225px'>";
        echo "<span class='count-span-photos'>".$pic_counter." of ".$total_pics."</span>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</li>";
        $pic_counter++;   
    }

    if ($i==1)
    {
        echo "<li></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";  
    echo "</div><!-- post-photo-slider END -->";
    echo "<hr class='hr4'>";

    ?>

</div><!-- photo end -->
```

Comment: Why?!? What's wrong with `$var = "Hello World ..the value is XYZ";` or `$xyz = 'XYZ'; $var = "Hello World ..the value is $xyz";`.... there's no valid use case for what you want to do, so why do you want to know how to do it

Comment: @MarkBaker  :this is just a simplest example, I have given. Actual requirement is much complex. It invloves much cumputation in php . the output of which should be again assigned to a php variable

Comment: If you absolutely, positive, simply must make your code so distorted to the point of being impossible to use; look at output buffering the result of the expression, and then injecting that into your code

Comment: Yes, we would need a "real" example and what you really hope to achieve.

Comment: So why not simply assign it to a variable? and use interpolation or concatenation to build your var? Like most developers do

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok I am gonna update my question with actual requirement

Comment: @Deva  you want generate the content for a .php  file so when loaded is executed  ?

Comment: @scaisEdge  :Actually I am calling a PHP file with ajax...the requirement is when the PHP file gets loaded, it should calculate the content from a PHP operation then the entire output should be assigned to again PHP variable so that it can be returned to AJAX in JSON

Comment: @MarkBaker Appreciate if you can explain how to achieve what you have suggested

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking for but maybe just `$rv = array(); foreach(... as $filename) { $rv[] = $filename; } echo json_encode($rv);` will do.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do it in this way

```
$var = "Hello World ..the value is <?php echo 'XYZ' ?>";
```

when you return this string to your javascript php code cannot be execute on client side!!!!

why do not return do this simple way?

```
$var = "Hello World ..the value is " . "XYZ";
```